# how to extract specific characters from a string

Tags: java, char, bufferedreader, getchar

i am working on a project in which i have to read data from a file and store that data into a string array.

String array position "0" should have first 13 characters of the file, string array position "1" should have next 13 characters of the file.
I tried to read only first 13 characters using getchar(), but i was having trouble using it, can anybody point out my error because when i try to run that on the app, the app crashes.

```
   InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.temp);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {

                while((string = br.readLine()) != null){
                string.getChars(0,13, buffer, 0);
                    String str = new String(buffer);
                    text.setText(str);  

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
```

here, buffer is a char type array.

Comment: What is the desired language?

Comment: Is that Java or what ?

Comment: yes, its java, i am doing android programming and i am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.substring(startIndex, endIndex)` to retrive a part of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why do ya use `readLine` when you are trying to split the string into chunks of 13 characters?

```
String str = "Some string that may or may not be longer than 13 characters";
int LENGTH = 13, off_multiplier = 0, read_size;    
char [] buffer = new char[LENGTH];

ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<String>();

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))){
    while( (read_size = reader.read(buffer, off_multiplier * LENGTH ,LENGTH)) != -1){
        string_array.add(new String(buffer,0,read_size));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Asad It's the string you wanna split, seems like I left it out when copy-pasting, fixed.

Comment: @Asad so was that what you were after? if it was, mark it as answer so others know.